# Running timeit in a for loop with index as input number

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeit

Im trying to run timeit to time a python function like so:

```
for i in range(1, 30):
    print 'The time for ' + str(i) + ' is ' + str(timeit.Timer('Fib(i)', 'from problem1 import Fib').timeit())
```

`global name 'i' is not defined` even though I have i defined in the start of the program as `global i`

When I run timeit like so:

```
print timeit.Timer('Fib(5)', 'from problem1 import Fib').timeit()
```

it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: You imported `Fib`, but not `i`. The code you're timing doesn't run in its caller's scope and doesn't have access to its caller's variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
for i in range(1, 30):
    t = timeit.Timer('Fib({:d})'.format(i), 'from problem1 import Fib').timeit()
    print('The time for {i:d} is {t:0.2f}'.format(i=i, t=t))
```

Comment: Few questions on what things do so I can learn if you dont mind. What does the {:d}, {i:d}, and {t:0.2f} do? and the format(i=i, t=t)?

Comment: I'm using the [format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). It looks daunting at first, but it is well worth the time to learn. `{:d}` is the same as `{0:d}` and it tells `format(i)` to replace it with the first argument of `format` formatted as an `int`. `{i:d}` is replaced with `i` formatted as an `int`. `{t:0.2f}` is replaced with `t` formatted as a float to 2 decimal places.

Comment: `'{:d}'.format(i)` is equivalent to `'%d' % (i,)`. `'{t:0.2f}'.format(t=t)` is equivalent to `'%0.2f' % (t,)`.